# First difference of logs of negative numbers causes trouble

Tags: stationarity, logarithm, augmented-dickey-fuller, differencing, sentiment-analysis

I have the following problem: I have a timeseries with the prices for a few futures, which is non-stationary (according to ADF test). If I apply first difference of logs, ADF shows stationarity.
But I also have one column in timeseries with news sentiment scores (from -1 to 1), and it seems like I can't apply first difference of logs to it.
This timeseries will be later used in ARIMAX. What should I do?
I think all dataset should be in the same I(1) or I(0) condition.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that the first difference of log prices are returns so what you have found is that the calculated return series is stationary. Not that that necessarily matters but I wasn't sure if you were aware of that. If you were, then apologies for noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Richard; you don't need to take the log of the (sentiment) negative numbers. Just pass the values of the sentiment factors time series as an exogenous factor in the ARIMAX(.) model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot take logs of negative numbers, but you also do not need to. Use sentiment scores as they are.